# Facebook share dialog does not close after posting or cancelling

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

Using v2.0 of the Facebook API, the share dialog popup doesn't close after the "Cancel" or "Post to Facebook" button has been selected. Previously, a 'redirect_uri' param was passed to the Feed endpoint, and this could be used to close the window. When trying to pass this param to the Share endpoint, however, I get the message: 'When using FB.ui, you should not specify a redirect_uri.'

Is there any way to force the popup window to close? And if not, might there be a problem with the API request? The link DOES get shared when "Post to Facebook" is selected, so I don't think it's an issue with login or permissions.

Here is what the API call looks like:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: location.href,
)}, function(response){});
```

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? i am having the same problem and interested?

Comment: Guys how do solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a preventDefault. I had the FB.ui action being triggered when an anchor tag was clicked. When I clicked the link, the page refreshed. Then when I'd click 'Post to Facebook' in the popup, I presume that the callback had nowhere to go.

What worked for me:

```
handleFbShare = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'https://your-url/',
  }, function(response){});
}

(...)

<a href="" className='button__facebook' onClick={this.handleFbShare}>Share on Facebook</a>
```

Hope that helps!